# Chrome Tab Extensions: getCurrent vs. getSelected?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm writing a Chrome extension. As part of the extension, I want to get the URL of the tab that the extension was called from. What's the difference between using:

```
chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function(tab) { var myTabUrl = tab.url; });
```

and

```
chrome.tabs.getCurrent(function(tab) { var myTabUrl = tab.url; });
```

?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

<s>`getCurrent` should be what you need, `getSelected` is a tab that is currently selected in a browser. When they could be different - maybe your extension runs some background cronjob in tabs, so that tab could be not currently selected by a user.</s>

Ok I got it all wrong apparently. `getCurrent` should be used only inside extension's own pages that have a tab associated with them (options.html for example), you can't use it from a background or popup page. `getSelected` is a tab that is currently selected in a browser.

As to your original question - you probably need neither of those two. If you are sending a request from a content script to a background page, then the tab this request is being made from is passed as a `sender` parameter.

Comment: outdated answer nowadays, see below

Answer (score 21):

Method `chrome.tabs.getSelected` has been deprecated. You should use `chrome.tabs.query` instead now.

You can't find the official doc for obsolete method `chrome.tabs.getSelected`. Here is the doc for method [`chrome.tabs.query`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-query).

Answer (score 4):

For those who is looking for working example of `chrome.tabs.query` instead of deprecated `chrome.tabs.getSelected`:

```js
chrome.tabs.query({
    active: true,
    lastFocusedWindow: true
}, function (tabs) {
    var myTabUrl = tabs[0].url;
});
```

Comment: Just to say that its tabs[0].url (tabs rather that tab)